# change uitableview footer dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a custom UITableViewCell that I am using as footer for UITableView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("footerCommentCell") as! FooterCommentTableViewCell
    cell.footerIndex = section
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

This footer has autolayout like 
http://joxi.ru/DrloGbpC4Eb3vA
1 - view 1
2 - view 2
3 - view 2 height constraint (`view2Height`)

At init phase `view2Height` is 0, and for some actions I want to change this constraint constant to another value, for example - 50, and make my header changed to.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override heightForFooterInSection and return 0 or 50 based on the requirement and reload table section.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        //return value based on condition 
    }
```

Comment: I can't get access to my footer cell in this method, so I can't change constraint

changing whole height won't give the result I want, because I use auto layout

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. When you say dynamic it means you need some condition to change it.
For ex :
Subclass two UITableviewCells and then just reload the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @2ank3th answer, you can get the cell/view of footer.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let footerView = tableView.footerViewForSection(0) as! FooterCommentTableViewCell 
// Your section number. (0 for understanding purpose)

// Then you can modify the height constraint and return the height of footer here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 44.0
}
```